# Round the body or around the body?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

I am teaching an English book and there is this sentence makes me confused:

> the heart pumps blood round the body....

Should it be *around* the body? If not, what is the reason and what's the difference?

Comment: @user405662 I disagree. The heart is inside the body, so how can it pump blood _into_ it? I expect the author used _round_ because _around_ suggests 'round the outside of' (Oxford Dictionaries say 'on every side of').

Comment: PS There isn't a hard and fast distinction between _round_ and _around_, but there's nothing wrong with the author's choice.

Comment: But my question is would it be ok if I use "around " instead?

Comment: Your original question was "Should it be _around_?" There isn't enough difference between them to make either word wrong.

Comment: Thanks a million for commenting on my questions

Comment: [Cambridge - round/around](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/around-or-round)